# How to fix 'Impossible de résoudre le conflit de classement entre French_CL_AI et French_BIN'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have an OLE DB with this query the two tables are in different databases :

```
SELECT E.EmployeeFullName, D.DepartmentId, D.Label
FROM DB1.HR.Employee AS E
LEFT JOIN DB2.HR.Department AS D ON D.DepartmentId=E.DeptId
```

When I execute the package I have the following error :

[image]

This is the message of the error :

> Impossible de résoudre le conflit de classement entre
> “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS” et “French_CI_AS” dans l’opération
> equal to.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, all content should be in English, that includes error messages.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from comparing two fields that do not have the same collation, so you have to specify the collation to use.
Your query should be like below :

```
SELECT E.EmployeeFullName, D.DepartmentId, D.Label
FROM HR.Employee AS E
LEFT JOIN HR.Department AS D ON D.DepartmentId=E.DeptId COLLATE FRENCH_CI_AS
```